# testing the response handling of an interceptor

Tags: angular

I want to test the below interceptor so that I can verify:

- show() is called on every request
- hide() is called on a response
- hide() is also called on a response error

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoadingIndicatorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.loadingIndicatorService.show();  // show()

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loadingIndicatorService.hide())  // hide()
    );
  }
}
```

How can I test the request and response behaviour of such an interceptor?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you read https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests and https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing?

Comment: Note that your loading indicator won't behave as you probably want it to behave if you ever send requests in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, the link to the testing-http-requests was really helpful. I totally missed that. 
Why do you think that the loading indicator doesn't behave as expected? The LoadingIndicatorService counts the number of parallel requests.

Comment: If it does, then fine. But show() and hide() lead to think that it shows up every time a request is sent and that it hides itself whenever a response comes back.